# disable precompiled header for a single file

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, cmake

I am working on a project with many `.cpp` files on `vs2013`, and using a precompiled header for them. I am using CMake to build my project.

But I have one `.c` file (let's call it `xyz.c`) for which I want to disable precompiled header.

I tried several methods, but if I enable precompiled headers to all `.cpp` file, it automatically turns on for the `.c` file as well. This is what I tried:

```
set_source_files_properties (xyz.c
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /Y-xyz.c )
```

Assuming that `/Yu` is on for all files, I just try to turn off this option for `xyz.c`.

If any one knows any method, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`/Y-`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hy7a92h.aspx) doesn't take arguments. Try:

```
set_source_files_properties(xyz.c
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /Y-)
```

Alternatively, instead of using `/Yu` on all files and disable it only for your `.c` file, you can use the opposite approach and only use `/Yu` for the `.cpp` files. Given your `.cpp` files are listed in a variable `SOURCES` and `my_pch.h` is your precompiled header:

```
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCES}
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /Yumy_pch.h)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but it still does not work

Comment: Did you clean your build directory before configuring again? I edited my answer with an alternative. If it doesn't work either, please edit your question with your complete CMake code

Comment: Thanks again for your response. It was very helpful, I will try another method later. got some other issue. thanks again.

Comment: I tried the other method and it works. First, I enable to use precompiled header for all file and then using another command /Y- , disabled it to particular files.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 10):

Starting from cmake 3.16 setting `/Y-` compiler option will not work. Correct way to disable precompiled headers for individual file is like this:

```
set_source_files_properties(non-pch.cpp PROPERTIES SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS ON)
```

Documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_sf/SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS.html

(Not so useful anyway)